# what is the integral of PAR radiation over total solar radiation

Tags: photosynthesis

This paper say 48%: What is the maximum efficiency with which photosynthesis can convert solar energy into biomass? -Zhu 2008

Also why does Zhu use 740 nm at high end of PAR wavelength!

My calculation says 43% (also using 7440 nm)

Have you done this integral? What did you find

Comment: What paper?  Could you give a name and / or link, please?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes the paper is: What is the maximum efficiency with which photosynthesis can convert solar energy into biomass? (Zhu,2008)